# Cannot get Php router to send correct header

Tags: php, regex, class

I have the following Class

```
class Route{

private $urls = array();

public function add($url, $function){
    $this->urls[str_replace('/', '\/', $url)] = $function;
}

public function dispatch(){
    ksort($this->urls);
    foreach ($this->urls as $url => $function) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . $url . '$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)){
            call_user_func($function, $match);
            break;
        } else{
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
}
}
```

When using the class like this

```
$route = new Route();

$route->add('/', function(){
echo 'test';
});

$route->add('/([a-zA-Z]+)', function($match){
    echo 'test <pre>';
    print_r($match);
});

$route->add('/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)', function($match){
    echo 'test <pre>';
    print_r($match);
});

$route->dispatch();
```

When visiting the root everything is fine, but when i visit the page with the link "/testing/test" or "/testing" a 404 message appears but the user function executes fine.

When i delete the following part

```
else{ header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); }
```

The function executes normally but then i cannot send a header if the page is not found. Is there another work around for this?

The main problem seems to be the break statement. When the key matches the request uri the loop continues.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the 404 only if the loop finishes without finding a match. Move the `header` call after the loop and return instead of break.

```
foreach ($this->urls as $url => $function) {
    if (preg_match('/^' . $url . '$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)){
        call_user_func($function, $match);
        return;
    }
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Or if there is some other logic that needs to happen in either case, you could set a variable like `$found` inside the loop.

```
$found = false;
foreach (...) {
    if (...) {
        call_user_func(...);
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    header(...)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for helping my understanding of Php. Just a beginner here on first real project.